# MySQL PHP count(*) returning something weird

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following query, expecting it to return an INTEGER, but it returns "Resource id #3"
What am I doing wrong?

```
$queryPlans = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM infostash.rooms");
echo $queryPlans;
```

There are actually 15 rows in this table, and I would like to return the number 15.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `php.net` (and it’s 20-something mirrors) down again so you couldn’t just read the–quite exhaustive–documentation? I don’t get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
$queryPlans = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM infostash.rooms");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($queryPlans);
echo $row[0];
```

[`mysql_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) isn't returning the result. It's returning a resource you can loop across and interrogate for rows (as above).

Answer (score 3):

mysql_query will return a php resource(see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

The returned resource should then be passed to mysql_fetch_assoc or similar.

Since you are only getting the count, you can use the following:

```
$queryPlans = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM infostash.rooms");
$count = mysql_result($queryPlans,0,0);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually expected behavior according to the documentation:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

It's a regular select that returns one row with one column and should be treated as such. You can call *mysql_fetch_array* on the result:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
$count = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a [result resource](http://uk.php.net/resource). You need another function the get "valuable information" from that resource. In this case [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)/[mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/mysql_row)/[mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object) as cletus pointed out. Or (since it's only a single value) [mysql_result()](http://php.net/mysql_result).
Any sql query may fail for various reasons. You should *always* check the return value of mysql_query(). If it's FALSE something went wrong and [mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql_error) can tell you more about it.

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_selecT_db(.., $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM infostash.rooms";
$queryPlans = mysql_query($query, $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));
$cRows = mysql_result($queryPlans, 0);
echo $cRows;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using the full query later (e.g. select *, rather than count(*)), you can save yourself a database hit by using [`mysql_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) on the full query. Example:

```
$queryPlans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM infostash.rooms");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($queryPlans);
echo "There were " . mysql_num_rows($queryPlans) . " results";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryPlans)){
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$queryPlans = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM infostash.rooms");
mysql_num_rows($queryPlans);

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: That always returns 1 since there's only one result record for a Count(*) without grouping.